# unable to `open` the file , but `lseek` is done without error

Tags: c++, c, unix

I am working on the `unix system calls`.
here in my code I want to `open` the file and perform `lseek` operation on that file.
please look into the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{

 int fd;


 fd = open("testfile.txt", O_RDONLY);
 if(fd < 0 );
   printf("problem in openning file \n");

 if(lseek(fd,0,SEEK_CUR) == -1)
   printf("cant seek\n");
 else
   printf("seek ok\n");

 exit(0);

}
```

my output is :

```
   problem in openning file 
   seek ok
```

My question is  :

1) why `open` system call is giving me the negative file descriptor ? (I have conformed that testfile.txt file is within the same directory)

2) Here I am unable to open the file(as because `open()` returns me negative file descriptor) , how `lseek` is successful without opening the file?

Comment: `if(fd < 0 );` <-- that semicolon is your entire then branch. Remove it.

Comment: The entire premise is flawed. Error due an extra semi-colon.

Comment: You just assumed the file desciptor is negativ. Assumptions without prove are dangerous as you see. ;-)

Answer (score 6):

In fact, you open the file successfully.

Just `if(fd < 0 );` is wrong, you need to remove the `;`

Answer (score 2):

Most APIs will tell you why an error occurred, and for system calls like `open()` that is achieved by looking at `errno` (and using `strerror()` to get a textual version of the error).  Try the following (with your errors removed):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{

 int fd;


 fd = open("testfile.txt", O_RDONLY);
 if(fd < 0 ) {   // Error removed here
   printf("problem in opening file: %s\n", strerror(errno));
   return 1;
 }

 if(lseek(fd,0,SEEK_CUR) == -1)   // You probably want SEEK_SET?
   printf("cant seek: %s\n", strerror(errno));
 else
   printf("seek ok\n");

 close(fd);

 return 0;

}
```

Comment: You probably know this, but `printf()` with `strerror()` can be abstracted by [perror()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/perror).